How to save email Message as an EML to a folder using MS-Graph and C#
I am trying to save an email to a windows folder retrieved using MS-Graph client and C#. I so far have
var firstEmail = _graphServiceClient.Users[senderAddress].MailFolders.Inbox.Messages[msgs[0].Id].Request().Expand("attachments").GetAsync().Result;

Please any help would be appreciated

The only endpoint that supports Export to the eml is the \Messages endpoint so take the Id your trying to use with the inbox folder and do
_graphServiceClient.Users[senderAddress].Messages[msgs[0].Id].Content

